# Blocking websites on a web app using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

I'm currently developing a web app that allows users to add a list of websites that they want to block i.e. preventing them from accessing the website from their browser.

Ideally I want to be able to block websites on **every** browser but this is difficult, so I narrowed my research to just **Chrome** for now. I came across the [chrome.webRequest api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples) which seems promising but it specifically says its for chrome extensions and am unsure if it would work for my web app.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for blocking websites on a web app, ideally using javascript. Any help is much appreciated!!

**EDIT**:

1) I forgot to mention that I'm using firebase for my backend.

2) People have been saying that I can't block websites outside the web apps scope, if I instead used electron to make the web app a desktop application would it then be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "block"? Prevent `XMLHttpRequest`s or what?

Comment: Preventing them from accessing the website :) Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Web apps can't block anything outside their scope/site. You need to write a browser extension. Extensions can use webRequest API.

Comment: If I instead made the web app a desktop application e.g. by using electron would I then be able to block websites?

Comment: @andrewdao i need your some help as i am working on same project

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you have a database containing URL of blocked websites. URLs are modified using your web app. That's one part. Now your problem is how to make the browser work with your database.

The only possible way for you to share blocked URLs with the browser is via API. You must have API that can communicate outside your web app.

Now browsers such as chrome/firefox give users the power to make changes inside and outside the [dom](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html). For chrome, you have chrome extension where Google provides API so the users can manipulate actions outsides regular actions such as manipulating dom. An example I can give that is closely related to your subject matter, which is an action activated before/after a user enters URL on the search box and for that, we use the following API from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

And it's same for Firefox.

Comment: But can I use the chrome API for a web app? or does my application have to be an extension?

Comment: It must be extension otherwise how will your app connect with browser action. Actually, I made an just like that. I used urlcrazy to get fake urls then my extension did the check and redirect part

Comment: Nope, electron won't help you.